# Weak entities: how to express in ORM?

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, object-role-modeling

In entity-relationship diagrams there's a weak entity type, which is an entity that has no key attribute. I would like to know what the object-role modelling equivalent is.

Comment: "which is an entity that has no key attribute"--Huh? Find a definition. If you don't know what it is in its method, how can you find an analogue? PS What has your research found? [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of weak entity type is incorrect. In ER, every entity type must have a primary key in any case. A weak entity type has a mandatory foreign key in its own primary key.

It's same in ORM, but even more general. An entity type which contains any mandatory role may only exist if the corresponding role is filled, so it is dependent on the existence of a role player. It is irrelevant whether that role is played by another entity type, or whether the object type playing that role gets mapped to another table. It is also irrelevant whether the mandatory role is part of any identifier (including the preferred identifier) though that's the situation where the description "weak" is likely to be used. However, the idea of "weak" is unnecessary to ORM and should not be used.

Note an ET is *not* the same thing as an ER entity, and not all ETs will necessarily be mapped to a table.

Answer (score 1):

An entity, A, is *weak* if it can't exist independently of another entity, B, and the identifying attributes of B form part of the identifying attributes of A. The relationship between A and B is said to be *identifying* in this case. This does not mean that A has no key attribute. A does have a key but its key attributes include attributes referencing the (primary) key of B.

In ORM this situation can be modelled using an mandatory role between A and B. There is an example in Terry Halpin's "brown book", page 307 [1].

The ORM notation is much more expressive than the ER concept of a weak entity. In ER modelling a dependent entity is usually considered weak only if the *preferred identifier* for the entity type references another entity type. In ORM you can express the dependency constraint "A cannot exist without B" independently of the identification schemes for A and B. Consider the example of Husband and Wife entities representing monogamous heterosexual marriage. One cannot exist without the other but the preferred identification scheme for one spouse does not have to include an identifier for the other.

[1] Halpin, Information Modeling and Relational Databases, 2nd Ed.

Comment: Nice introduction, but your second paragraph is incorrect. p307 Fig8(b) shows an external (preferred) uniqueness constraint, not an equality constraint. This uniqueness constraint is not what makes Dependant weak - the mandatory role of Employee does that by saying "every Dependant is a dependent of some Employee". An equality constraint would be illegal here as a PersonName cannot equal an Employee.

Comment: Thanks @cliffordheath. You are quite right and I totally misunderstood the example in Halpin's book. I edited my answer.